# Pointer to expression result in go

Tags: go

Can I create a pointer to expression result without making new variable in Go?

```
package test

func foo(*uint32) {

}

func main() {
    foo(&(uint32(time.Now().Unix()))) //this line gives me error
    //cannot take the address of uint32(...
}
```

Comment: Why would you be able to take the address of an undeclared variable? If it doesn't exist in the memory you can't get the address.

Comment: [Addressability is discussed in the language specifcaiton](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators). The int32 value 0 is not addressable.

Comment: Thanks! But is there any other standard method that creates pointer?
As I can see, this works just fine...
func getAdress(s int32) *int32 {
 return &s
}

Comment: @VitaliyAndrianovin this particular case, you can use `new(int32)` to create a pointer to an `int32` with value `0`. If you need a pointer to a non-zero value, a variable declaration would be necessary. You can then pass a pointer to the variable. (you can't pass a pointer to a constant)

Comment: Ok it was a bad example with 0 constant =D.
I'll replace it with `time.Now().Unix()`

Comment: Either assign to a variable or write a the `getAddress` helper as you propose.  Why do you need the address?  Perhaps there's a higher-level problem that can be solved without taking the address of a function return.

Comment: Just trying to .Marshal() big message with protobuf. So I have to use automatically generated code from .proto file. And this code has strange signature with lots of pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question comments, OP says that the pointers are needed for a protobuf message.

The [proto](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto) package provides helper functions for creating pointers to integers and other values.

Use the [proto.Uint32](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Uint32) function to get a pointer to a uint32.

```
x.Time = proto.Uint32(u)
```